# Replacing null by zero

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I need to write a query which need to replace email result by 0 when it's null

Comment: You need to add to your post more details about the database. And show us what are your attemps or what is the problem you are having.

Comment: Which DBMS? MySQL is not sql-server!

Comment: I'm a bit confused actually what are you trying to do? update the database to have a value of 0 when the value is null?

Answer (score 3):

`UPDATE tblName SET email = 0 WHERE email is null;`

Answer (score 1):

Use the `ifnull()` function:

```
ifnull(email,"0")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `coalesce` function:

```
SELECT COALESCE(email, '0') FROM some_table
```